# How to use Hostcontrol RP API BETA

Tags: php, api

We want to use resello or hostcontroll api, but we can use some method because this api doesnt have this methods in own api. When send msg via thikits for suports, they send this link for us https://kb.hostcontrol.com/Slimsite
in this link have new api document for hostcontroll. We get this and want to use it.

Our problem is here. In this document in Access and Authentication part, will be use base url links ok? 
https://rp01.hostcontrol.com/api

When I want to use this links i have 404 error?!
Why api base url have 404 error?

pls helpe us

thanks

Answer (score 0):

hi i find my answer qustions .. this link true is :

https://rp01.hostcontrol.com/api/v1/domain-host

after api word **/v1**/...

hapy code